# Find all PRTs having a hypotenuse of $65$

Tags: number-theory

> A Pythagorean Right Triangle (PRT) is a right triangle all of whose sides have positive integer lengths. Find all PRTs having a hypotenuse of $65$.

We need $m^2+n^2 = 65^2$, but we know that since $65 = 5 \cdot 13$ any $m,n$ satisfying $m^2+n^2 = 5^2$ or $m^2+n^2 = 13^2$ will also satisfy $m^2+n^2 = 65^2$. How can we continue?

Comment: see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PythagoreanTriple.html and the solution is $$63^2+16^2=65^2$$

Comment: @Xammm, it's $m^2 + n^2 = 65^2$ not $65$.

Comment: The full set is $16^2 + 63^2 = 65^2$ , $25^2 + 60^2 = 65^2$, $33^2 + 56^2 = 65^2$, $39^2 + 52^2 = 65^2$ and perhaps $0^2 + 65^2 = 65^2$.   Of these $16^2 + 63^2 = 65^2$ and $33^2 + 56^2 = 65^2$ are primitive while $25^2 + 60^2 = 65^2$ and  $39^2 + 52^2 = 65^2$ involve multiples of $5$ or of $13$

Comment: @Guru oh you're righ. Maybe I'm still drunk xD.